# WCF consuming JAX-WS service with response elements not in the XSD

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, xsd, jax-ws

We are using .NET 4.x WCF to consume a JAX-WS service. The proxy generated from the WSDL and XSD by "Add Service Reference" produces code which can correctly call the service. The service response, however, uses a root element name which is not defined in the XSD. The proxy returns a null result, presumably because the element name wasn't recognized, so the rest of the response envelope is ignored.

The SOAP response looks like this. Notice the root element in the body is named `txLife22814Type`:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
  <soapenv:Body>
     <ns3:txLife22814Type xmlns:ns3="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2" xmlns:ns2="http://dtcc.com/lnapm/service/">
     <ns3:TXLife>
          ...snip...
    </ns3:TXLife>
    </ns3:txLife22814Type>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The relevant portion of the XSD looks like this. Notice the root element is named `Tx22814` and there is no `txLife22814Type` associated with the `TXLife_22814_Type` complexType:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Tx22814" type="TXLife_22814_Type"/>
    <xs:element name="Tx22815" type="TXLife_22815_Type"/>
    <xs:element name="Tx22816" type="TXLife_22816_Type"/>
    <xs:complexType name="TXLife_22814_Type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="TXLife" type="TXLife_IPT_Type"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

The rest of the response matches the XSD just fine. (I have not posted the full WSDL and XSD as they are quite large, many hundreds of lines.)

On the sending side, the operation request takes this same type (`TXLife_22814_Type`) as an input parameter (actually it's a byref that is modified by the service), the WSDL for the call references the correct XSD name (`Tx22814`), and it works.

I tried adding a second root to the XSD which maps to the same type:

```
    <xs:element name="txLife22814Type" type="TXLife_22814_Type"/>
```

This caused the *request* to fail, which surprised me. I wondered if WCF can't disambiguate the type, although I would expect the explicit use of the `Tx22814` name in the WSDL should handle that. The WSDL (heavily edited for readability to show only the relevant operation) looks like this. The operation or "message" of interest here is `isProducerTrainedRequest`:

```
<wsdl:definitions ...snip... >
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://dtcc.com/lnapm/service/">
      <xsd:import namespace="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2" schemaLocation="DTCC_PM_ACCORD_V2.28.xsd"/>
      <xsd:element name="MessageHeader">
          ... snip ...
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="isProducerTrainedRequest">
     <wsdl:part element="ns1:Tx22814" name="Tx22814"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="isProducerTrainedResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="ns1:Tx22814" name="Tx22814Response"/> 
  </wsdl:message>
```

I wrote an AfterReceiveReply interceptor and did a string-replace on the mangled tag, and then the rest of the proxy works, but that is clearly a hack that we'd prefer to keep out of production code.

We do not own the service. The service providers do not have other .NET consumers. They claim all of their Java-based clients are not having a problem. (Maybe JAX-WS or Java in general assumes some sort of element name decoration? Or ignores it?)

Has anyone seen this? Does anyone have a solution? Is there maybe a way to decorate something in Reference.cs to either translate or map element names, or something along those lines? I am not a SOAP or XML expert; do I misunderstand something about SOAP and/or XSD element naming rules? Can the XSD be altered to satisfy both the request and response?

Comment: why did the request fail after the change? did the request on the wire look different?

Comment: I really wish I knew. I was "flying remotely" suggesting changes to the another dev, so I couldn't put my hands on the code myself. Once he got the interceptor hack working he reported success to his boss and management decreed, "Move on." Corporate America FTW!